# How it is possible to be one God in three persons (Jesus, Holy Ghost, and God the Father)?

Tags: nature-of-god, trinity, philosophy

> 1)”Hear, O Israel: The Lord our God, the Lord is one. [**Deuteronomy 6:4**](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Deuteronomy+6%3A4&version=ESV)
>
> 2)And the Word( Jesus) became flesh and dwelt among us, and we have seen his glory, glory as of the only Son[a] from the Father, full of grace and truth.” [**John 1:14**](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=John+1%3A14&version=ESV)
>
> 3)In the beginning was the Word, and the Word was with God, and the Word was God.” [**John 1:1**](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=John+1%3A1&version=ESV)
>
> 4)He is the image of the invisible God, the firstborn of all creation. For by[a] him all things were created, in heaven and on earth, visible and invisible, whether thrones or dominions or rulers or authorities—all things were created through him and for him. And he is before all things, and in him all things hold together. [**Coossians 1:15-17**](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Colossians+1%3A15-17&version=ESV)
>
> 5)”and behold, a voice from heaven said, “This is my beloved Son, with whom I am well pleased.” [**Mathew 3:17**](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew+3%3A17&version=ESV)

According to these 5 verses, it tells that Jesus was created before all the rest. And in another verse says that Jesus always existed. And in another verse, it says that Jesus is God. This where I can’t explain. How can Jesus, Holy Ghost and God be one God?

In first, I thought that Jesus and Holy Ghost are 2 different creators that are uncreated and God is the uncreated one which it will equal 3 gods.

**CLARIFICATION**

I had a conversation today with my religious teacher, and I asked him, “sir, can I ask you something?” And he said, “yes, you can” and I asked him, “is that true that Jesus is God’s creation?” And he said, “no, Jesus is God, in fact, he part from trinity of one God.” And I asked, “how can this be possible?” And he said, “I don’t know”. What I found that in Bible says that God has sent Jesus, what is that suppose to mean? Is Jesus another creator like God Himself? And in another verse I find this:

> ”this is My beloved son! So listen to him”

Which it indicates that Jesus and God are different and not 3 in one God. But some rumors say opposite that Jesus, Holy Ghost and Father are three persons in one God.

> “I’ll be a Father to you, and you will be My sons and daughters, Says the Lord Almighty” [**[Corinthians, 6:18]**](https://biblehub.com/2_corinthians/6-18.htm)

**My questions are:**

1. How it is possible to be 3 persons in one God?
2. Is there anything in Bible that clarifies the concept of trinity?

Can anyone please find something in Bible that can clearly explain how this is possible?

Comment: Your second question is a duplicate of [What is the Biblical basis for the doctrine of the Trinity?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/72/6071)

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE!  This is a site the discusses the beliefs of many Christian denominations and traditions.  You're asking what we call a [truth question](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3527/we-cant-handle-the-truth).  You should expect the question to be closed unless you specifiy the Christian tradition or denomination from which point of view answers will be provided.  For more information visit our [help center](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Part 2 of your question (the only answerable part) is a duplicate of [What is the Biblical basis for the doctrine of the Trinity?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/72/what-is-the-biblical-basis-for-the-doctrine-of-the-trinity). The question of "How" is a philosophical one, and so off topic here.

Comment: @DJClayworth What's the "[philosophy](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/philosophy)" tag for, then?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

God is not a person.  God is a Being.

Within the One Being of God subsist the three persons of the Father, the Son, and the Holy Spirit.

Together, these three make up the One Being of God.

When Jesus was baptised in the River Jordan, all three were present: the Father whose voice was heard from heaven, the Son who was being baptised, and the Holy Spirit who appeared in the form of a dove.

That is why, when the Son died, the Father and the Holy Spirit did not also die.  The Being of God was not killed when the Son was killed because the Son is not the Father, the Father is not the Son, and the Holy Spirit is neither Father nor Son.

There has only ever been the One Being of God and there will only ever be the One Being of God.

Expressions such as "person", "Father" and "Son" are used to help us grasp the concept of a complex creator God, although it must be noted that the pre-mortal Jesus was never created, but was active in creation, along with the Holy Spirit.

The best Bible verses to explain this are in John 1:1-5 and 14:

> In the beginning was the Word, and the Word was with God, and the Word was God.  He was with God in the beginning.  Through him all things were made; without him nothing was made that has been made.  In him was life, and that life was the light of men.  The light shines in the darkness, but the darkness has not understood it...  The Word became flesh and made his dwelling among us.  We have seen his glory, the glory of the One and Only, who came from the Father, full of grace and truth."

Jesus is the Word.  Jesus came to earth to be born of a woman.  Jesus was God with us, back then. The Son laid down his life then took it up again and has returned to heaven, from whence he first came.

Edit: To Subsist, within the context of the Being of God, is To Exist, To Be.

Response to additional question: 2 Corinthians 6:18 must be read within the context of the previous verses about Christians not being yoked with unbelievers. They are being told to have nothing to do with pagans and idolatry.  Verse 18 is a quote from 2 Samuel 7:14 where God, through the prophet Samuel, makes promises to David regarding his kingdom.  God says “I will be his father and he shall be my son.  When he does wrong I shall punish him...  But my love will never be taken away from him as I took it away from Saul.”  David was not God’s literal son.  This is the explanation given in the NIV Study Bible notes:

> This familial language expresses the special relationship God promises to maintain with David’s descendants... It marks him as the one God has chosen and enthroned to rule in his name as the official representative of God’s rule over his people. ”
>
> The Christians in Corinth are being reminded of their special relationship with God.  Verse 16 explains: “I will live with them and walk among them, and I will be their God, and they will be my people.”
>
> Romans 8:14 says that those who are led by the Spirit of God are sons of God.  In other words, all who have entered into the new covenant Christ Jesus established are adopted into God’s family.  It’s a spiritual relationship.   Ephesians 1:5 explains: “In love he predestined us to be adopted as his sons through Jesus Christ.”

There is only one Son of God, and that is Jesus, who brought with him his divine nature which was added to his human nature.  Those who belong to Christ are adopted into God’s family as sons and daughters, but not physically.  2 Corinthians 6:18 is about our spiritual relationship with God.

Comment: Then how do you explain this verse from Bible that says, **”Father: Today, I shall be your father.”**?

Comment: @Alex A - please give me the Bible verse you refer to and I will look into it tomorrow.  I have to sign off for tonight (it's evening here in the U.K.)

Comment: Voila! I have given you.

Comment: @Alex A - Response and explanation about 2 Corinthians 6:18 given under my Edit. I'm strugging to understand what this verse has to do with the Trinity, though.

Comment: well, I see that it is says, “...first born of all…” which makes me think Jesus is God’s creation. And only He is eternal and not Jesus.

Comment: @Alex A - The word "first born" does NOT mean first created.  The Greek word for 'first created' is NEVER applied to Jesus. Why don't you ask a question about this?

Comment: @AlexA Jesus was uncreated: John 1:1-2, Colossians 1:15-20, Revelation 22:13

Comment: @Lesley So when Jesus died, the God lost part of it?

Answer (score 6):

Contrary to the way some may view this question, it is not a "truth" question but a "how" one. "How is it possible," you ask, given that the tiny selection of isolated verses you quote appear at first sight to be contradictory? You are not questioning the truthfulness of those verses but taking them as a given. You are not questioning the truthfulness of the Christian Trinity doctrine (one Being of God subsisting in three uncreated 'persons'), but asking how it is possible that this be so.

It could only be possible if all three who subsist in the one Being of God are uncreated. If one, two, or all three of them had to be created in order to start existing at a given point in time, then the entire Christian faith would be utter nonsense, and the doctrine of the Trinity as gleaned from the Bible would be rubbish. It logically follows that it could only be possible if the Holy Spirit had distinct personality and uncreated existence as does the Word (the Son, who later added human nature to his divine nature in order to become the man, Jesus).

This is where an additional comment is needed, where you stated, "According to these 5 verses, it tells that Jesus was created before all the rest."  Your misunderstand of those verses is causing you difficulty in understanding "how it is possible". None of those verses state that the Word (the Son, who later became Jesus) was ever created. This is where you need a grasp of the meaning of the ancient Greek words in the New Testament which have been variously translated into English as 'first-born' and 'only-begotten'. Never in the Bible are words used of Jesus that are to be translated as having had a starting point in time, by being created, or even pro-created. But that is not what you ask about, and I will not go into that here. Fresh questions are required. Let it just be pointed out that those who cannot see the uncreated nature of Christ in scripture, cannot see any possibility of the Trinity doctrine being biblical. Their interpretation of verses about Jesus can be based on misunderstanding what critically important biblical words mean, and may cause them to make serious changes to their own translations of the Bible, to weaken the import of the uncreated nature of Christ, and how "He made everything that was made" (John 1:3), logically meaning that he could not have been made (created) himself. I add this last paragraph to help get you over the 'hump' that prevents you grasping how it is indeed, possible, for the one eternal Being of God to subsist in three equally eternal 'persons'.

Answer (score 4):

Within the One Deity there is a perfection of unity.

Said Jesus :

> I and my Father are one (John 10:30 - KJV - εγω και ο πατηρ εν εσμεν)

But Paul also speaks of :

> the fullness of God (Ephesians 3:19 - KJV - το πληρωμα του θεου)

If, therefore, Deity is, in essence, fullness ; and if both the Father and the Son share that fulness ; and if there is no limit to that divine fulness . . .

. . and both share that unlimited fulness, in one Holy Spirit . . .

. . . then I believe it becomes clear (to faith, and to faith alone) that Deity exists in a perfection of divine unity. And in that divine nature, dwells the Person of God.

And from within that Deity has come One whom the Father declared :

> This is my beloved Son ... (Matthew 3:17 - KJV - εστιν ο υιος μου ο αγαπητος )

who in his turn declared :

> I and my Father are one.

Answer (score 3):

> "The Father is God, the Son is God, the Holy Spirit is God, they are
>   not three gods but one God' says the Athanasian Creed

The Scripture explains how the Father, the Son and the Holy Spirit are seen as the "one God".

1. **One God, one Lord** (1 Corinthians 8:6)

In this passage, the Father is said to be the one God (*eis theos*) whilst Jesus Christ is the one Lord (*eis kyrios*). The Greek phrase *eis theos* and *eis kyrios* are coined by Paul using the *Shema* of Deuteronomy 6:4 where it says that God (*theos*) is that Lord (*kurios*) who is one (*eis*).

Here, we have seen that the Father and Jesus Christ are both equally having divine titles!

2. **Divine Nature** (Galatians 4:8).

In Galatians 4:8, Paul says that those gods are "by nature not gods".

In 1 Corinthians 8, the two persons (the Father and Jesus) are both having divine titles. In that text, Paul contrasted them against the false gods. Both the Father and Jesus have the *same nature* (nature = essential attributes) of being above the *all things*, being the source of them.

3. **One Adam, One flesh** (Genesis 1-2, 5:2).

In Genesis 1-2, it says that the female came from the ribs of the male and that God breathed the spirit of life into the male alone. Therefore, the female derived her being (both body and spirit) from the male. In that sense, they are really of same being and of same nature. So the male says that the female is *flesh of his flesh and bones of his bones*. Also, in their union they are called *one flesh*. In Genesis 5:2, God called them "*Adam*" (not Adams). Thus, a singular for two persons signifying their nature.

4. **Three persons, One Name** (Matthew 28:19)

In this text, the *Trinity* is of same name (Adonai/YHWH) which signifies their one *eternal* essence or nature (Exodus 3:14 LXX).

Note

Philippians 2:10-11 calls Jesus Lord (Greek: *kyrios)* in the sense of *Adonai* (not *Adoni* as Messiah from Psalm 110:1) based on Isaiah 45:23 (LXX). This supports *kyrios* in 1 Corinthians 8:6 as a divine title.

**Conclusion**

Scripture explicitly shows the idea of a *singular* name being addressed to *plurality* of persons.

Genesis 5:2
Male and female = one Adam, not two Adams

1 Corinthians 8:6 
Father and Jesus = one God, one Lord (not two Gods/Lords)

The the Father, Jesus and the Holy Spirit, who all are of same nature, are not three gods but one God just as Adam and Eve, who are of same nature, are not two Adams but one Adam in Genesis 5:2.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following analogy. The Greeks established the parallel line postulate, and Euclid wrote of it. He and succeeding mathematicians were perplexed why they could not use their other postulates and axioms to prove it. Then Lobachevsky and other mathematicians discoverd non-Euclidean geometries where parallel lines DO meet. The fact of whether parallel lines meet or not is a basic axiom of your mathematics and your world. It is a given, it does not have a cause. There is no why to be answered.

The Old Testament strongly emphasizes the unity of God. There is one God, not many.

The New Testament describes the different roles of a Father, a Son and the Holy Spirit. It descibes their unity. Jesus said in John's gospel, "I and the Father are One." It describes their distinctness, such as when Jesus is asked when the Kingdom of Israel would be restored and other prophesied events would occur and in Matthew 24 says:

> “Now concerning that day and hour no one knows—neither the angels in
>   heaven, nor the Son —except the Father only."

There are many statements in the New Testament that show the different roles of the members of the Trinity. They are described, but not explained. They are revealed as being. That just is the way God is. Since God is eternal and unchanging, God has always been this way so there is no cause for Him being this way. He just is. Like the parallel line postulate, we live in a universe whose axioms are consistent with the nature of God as He is. God's triune nature is the bedrock on which the universe was constructed.

Why do the Old and New Testament seemingly disagree? If two things are very close to each other and you are far from them, they look like one thing. The New Testament gives us a more up close view of God, allowing us to distinguish features that could not be seen with the earlier information we were given. However, that distinction between the trinity was present in the Old Testament, just not in focus. When Jesus met the two men walking to Emmaus in Luke 24:

> 25 He said to them, “How unwise and slow you are to believe in your
>   hearts all that the prophets have spoken! 26 Didn’t the Messiah have
>   to suffer these things and enter into His glory?” 27 Then beginning
>   with Moses and all the Prophets, He interpreted for them the things
>   concerning Himself in all the Scriptures.

If the Son of God tells us that it was all spelled out in the Old Testament, but we were too blind to see it, then it must be there, so we should look closer.

Answer (score 2):

As has already been noted, Jesus is "one" with God in the sense of unity. Hence Jesus gives the following prayer:

> John 17:20-23 My prayer is not for them alone. I pray also for those
> who will believe in me through their message, 21 that all of them may
> be one, Father, just as you are in me and I am in you. May they also
> be in us so that the world may believe that you have sent me. 22 I
> have given them the glory that you gave me, that they may be one as we
> are one— 23 I in them and you in me—so that they may be brought to
> complete unity. Then the world will know that you sent me and have
> loved them even as you have loved me.

Furthermore, it is good to note that many have been addressed as God who are not literally God. Only when Jesus is referred to as God do people start demanding that it be taken literally (producing all manner of contradiction). Moses was referred to as God (Exodus 7:1), Angels have been referred to as God (all over the OT, like the angel in the burning bush in Exodus 3), and the Jewish People have been addressed as gods (Psalms 82, John 10:33-36).

> Exodus 7:1 Then the Lord said to Moses, “See, I have made you like God to Pharaoh, and your brother Aaron will be your prophet.
>
> John 10:33-36 “We are not stoning you for any good work,” they replied, “but for blasphemy, because you, a mere man, claim to be God.” 34 Jesus answered them, “Is it not written in your Law, ‘I have said you are “gods”’[d]? 35 If he called them ‘gods,’ to whom the word of God came—and Scripture cannot be set aside— 36 what about the one whom the Father set apart as his very own and sent into the world? Why then do you accuse me of blasphemy because I said, ‘I am God’s Son’?

In reality, Jesus never says of himself that he is God, but always maintains that he is the Son of God. It is clear from an honest reading of the scriptures that no one in the scriptures literally considered Jesus to be God Almighty himself, but all maintained that Jesus was the Son thereof, who held a lesser position at the right-hand of God.

> Mark 16:19 After the Lord Jesus had spoken to them, he was taken up into heaven and he sat at the right hand of God.
>
> Luke 22:69 But from now on, the Son of Man will be seated at the right hand of the mighty God.”
>
> Acts 2:33 Exalted to the right hand of God, he has received from the Father the promised Holy Spirit and has poured out what you now see and hear.
>
> Romans 8:34 Who then is the one who condemns? No one. Christ Jesus who died—more than that, who was raised to life—is at the right hand of God and is also interceding for us.
>
> Hebrews 1:3 The Son is the radiance of God’s glory and the exact representation of his being, sustaining all things by his powerful word. After he had provided purification for sins, he sat down at the right hand of the Majesty in heaven.

Indeed, there is an abundance of scripture that clearly differentiates and subordinates Jesus to God Almighty. Here's a great verse from Paul:

> 1 Cor 15:27-28 27 For he “has put everything under his feet.”[c] Now when it says that “everything” has been put under him, it is clear that this does not include God himself, who put everything under Christ. 28 When he has done this, then the Son himself will be made subject to him who put everything under him, so that God may be all in all.

Comment: Of course they are one in unity but that is not what John 10:30 is teaching. The Son and the Father are one in nature. The Jews wanted to stone Jesus vs31, why? Vs33 they accused of blasphemy because Jesus made Himself out God. Why does Jesus bring up Psalm 82:6, which btw is not about unity. Jesus is being His own commentary. He makes the point that if the judges/men at Psalm 82:6 can be merely called "gods," then He could not be guilty of blasphemy for calling Himself THE (singular, one and only) "Son of God." (John 3:16). Read the trial record at Matthew 26:57-67.

Comment: @Mr.Bond The Jews in that passage, in the same breath, accused him of breaking the Sabbath. Maybe don't take your theology from the angry, mistaken mob trying to kill Christ?

Comment: Ryan: Your Biblically uninformed. Whether or not the Jews correctly or incorrectly understood Jesus or were mistaken is not the issue. What did Jesus say that caused the Jews to accuse Him of blasphemy resulting in His crucifixion/death? Jn 5:18. Is Jesus the literal Son of His Father? Jn 8:58, Did Jesus exist before Abraham was born? Jn 10:33. What did Jesus say that made the Jews say, "He made Himself out God?" Jn 19:7, What law did Jesus break according to the Jews by making Himself out the Son of God? The simple fact is that the Jews did not believe Jesus just like you don't believe Him.

Comment: @Mr.Bond if you wanted to know what Jesus actually claimed of himself you would pay attention to his response rather than to the mobs false accusations. He claimed of himself to be the Son of God and considered that to be a lesser claim than what the scriptures asserts of his accusers: that they are gods. Jesus reveals this relation to us - but that revelation is not good enough for you - so you reject it and try to treat it as a mere appellation. If you believed Jesus then you would believe who he claims to be rather than attempting to redefine terms to fit your preconceptions.

Comment: @Mr.Bond Furthermore, if you were familiar with the scriptures you would know it is not uncommon for those who are not God to be addressed as if God. Moses was made God to Pharaoh (Exodus 7:1), various angels throughout the OT were addressed as if God - and even YHWY - like the Angel in the burning bush (Exodus 3), and in general those who have received the Word of God are called gods as in John 10. Those who think it is sufficient to find a reference to Jesus as God to establish that he is literally God Almighty himself, let alone the Trinity, are ignorant of the word’s biblical precedence

Comment: Ryan. The Bible does designate certain persons as "gods." Moses is one of them, Exodus 7:1, See I make you a god to Pharaoh, and your brother Aaron shall be your prophet."  Cross-reference this with Exodus 4:16 (And he shall be even to thee in place of a mouth, and thou shalt be to him IN PLACE OF GOD).  A definite relationship was involved. Moses is not literally God, only "a god" representing THE GOD. On the other hand Jesus Christ is literally identified as God who became flesh, John 1:14. Also, the angel of the Lord is not literally an angel, He is the pre-incarnate Jesus Christ.

Comment: @Mr.Bond You are exactly correct concerning Moses: him being called God was in reference to him serving as God's representative. And Jesus is God's perfect representative and the sole mediator of the New Covenant. Jesus is the one like Moses - Moses foreshadows Christ. Unless very explicit scripture can be found to justify interpreting 'God' literally when applied to Christ then we ought to follow biblical precedence.

And no - Jesus never is or was an angel. Hebrews 1 goes out of its way to deny any such thing.

Comment: Ryan. Does John 20:28 literally apply to Christ? Does 2 Peter 1:1 apply to Christ? How about Titus 2:13? Or Revelation 1:8 Why do you think I made a big deal out of Jesus being accused of blasphemy including at His trial at Matthew 26. The Jews have "idioms." One such idiom is the "son of" idiom as explained here: https://biblicalstudies.org.uk/pdf/grace-journal/06-2_16.pdf So when Caiaphas ask Jesus to swear as to His identity, Matt 26:63 he specifically said 1, are you the Christ and 2, are you the Son of God? At Luke 22:70 Jesus says, Yes, I am." The Jews knew exactly what Jesus meant.

Comment: Continued. Regarding the angel of the Lord my point was that Jesus is not an actual angel. So who is the angel of the Lord? He first appears as the angel of the Lord at Genesis 16:7. Please read the rest of the chapter to see what he was able to do with regards to Hagar, vs10. See vs13. Now, at Genesis 17:1-2, God appears physically to Abraham. "I am God Allmighty; Walk before Me and be blameless. I will establish My covenant between Me and you, And I will multiply you exceedingly. Question? Is the being who multiplied Hagar's descendants the same being who multiplied Abram's descendants?

Comment: @Mr.Bond it is not a question of whether those verses literally apply to Christ - but of whether the term 'God' is applied in a literal fashion or in a symbolic fashion. There is precedence for one who is not God being addressed as if God on account of their serving as God's representative - and Christ is identified as the perfect representative and image of God. This simultaneously means he is not God - for one is spoken of as an image of themselves or as a representative of themselves. You haven't presented any scriptures that would demand a literal interpretation of the term.

Comment: Additionally, while "son of" maybe used as an idiom - never does "son of X" = "X themselves." Nor is Jesus as the "Son of God" an idiom. It carries the natural meaning of being begotten by God (Luke 1:35). Nor again is there *any* precedence in Judaism for "Son of God" = "God." Israel is referred to as Son of God (Exodus 4:22). And continuing to insist that Jesus is the angel of the Lord in the OT is foolishness - you are ignoring Hebrews 1: "For to which of the angels did He ever say, 'You are My Son, Today I have fathered You?'"

Comment: Yes! Please do, thank you!

Comment: @Mr.Bond You are welcome, good luck on your theological journey.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138894/discussion-between-mr-bond-and-ryan-pierce-williams).

Answer (score 1):

**According to trinitarians, God is One because there is only one uncreated substance in all of reality. That one uncreated substance is also three persons.**

There are two crucial points you have to understand to make sense of this seemingly contradictory language about God.

1. The term "person" does not mean "being."
2. "God is One" refers to His substance, not to the fact that He is tri-person.

Also related: [How does Jesus' pre-incarnational existence relate to oneness pentecostalist godhead doctrine?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/64400/how-does-jesus-pre-incarnational-existence-relate-to-oneness-pentecostalist-god/64403#64403)

Answer (score 0):

Years ago this concept was put to me like this, being one person I have many roles in this life:
1) When I was created in my mother's womb, I became a son
2) Years later, I got married, so then I became a husband
3) And soon thereafter, my wife and I became parents, me being the father.

So with those 3 roles (and I have many more), I have different responsibilities, but I am still one person.  I know this is way oversimplification of a very complex issue, it did help me understand a little the concept of God being 3 in 1.  And, I also came to the realization we humans are finite beings here on earth.  Our God is Infinite.  Without finite minds we cannot possibly fully grasp the infinite possibilities of an infinite God.

Answer (score -1):

**Mystery of Godliness** Even the great Apostle Paul realized that to understand God in totality was impossible. He often spoke of the **mystery of godliness**. (1 Corinthians 2:7, 4:1, Ephesians 1:9, 5:32. Colossians 1:26, 2:2, 1 Timothy 3:16)

> And without controversy, great is the mystery of Godliness; God was manifest in the flesh, justified in the Spirit, seen of angels, preached unto the nations, believed on in the world, received up into glory. (1 Timothy 3:16; notice the mentioning of the Tri-unity: God, flesh: Jesus, Spirit)

The Pre-nicene church theologians tried to explain this mystery with the example of **the Sun in our sky**. There is one Sun, but it is manifest on Earth by the appearance of light and heat. The Sun represented the Father, the Light was the Light of the world (Jesus), and the life empowering heat was the Holy Spirit. All metaphors and imageries have their limitations, to be sure; but they do shed some light that help us to envision in our minds what God is like. *We see through a mirror dimly...*

The Saint Patrick of Ireland used the **three-leaf clover** to to explain to the natives what the Tri-unity was like. Three leaves on one stem. This illustration was effective in causing the Irish to believe in the God of the Bible!

The comment of a previous Answer that "God was a **Being** not a person" comes close to grasping the truth. Our anthropological understanding of a "person" gets in the way of grasping the uniqueness of the Godhead...of the Tri-unity that is God...of the 'mystery' of Godliness.

A Hebrew scholar may be more adept at explaining Deuteronomy 6:4, but it was alleged that the word "One" (*Hear O  Israel, the LORD is One*) is a **compound word**, such as a bunch of grapes with many grapes is still *one* bunch.

And we do recall that the very beginning of the book of Genesis, in the Creation account, begins with **Let Us make man in our image...** GOD is mentioned; Jesus, the WORD, is said to have been there (John 1:1-3); and the SPIRIT moved over the face of the waters. Tri-unity!?

{Some explain the plural as a "plural of majesty" in Hebrew vernacular. But the three aspects of God are still mentioned here.}

Answer (score -2):

Perhaps the key to understanding the Trinity is to consider that God has the ability to extend Himself, and the two extensions of God are Jesus and the Holy Spirit. Think of God as a tree and it having two branches, those branches are Jesus and the Holy Spirit. Three Persons, but still One God.

Comment: This makes it sound like the Son and the Spirit are created, which is heretical to trinitarians.

Comment: @curiousdannii, I'm not saying that they were created, rather think of Jesus and the Holy Spirit as branches of a tree and that tree is God.

Comment: That's a better analogy. You should [edit] this to explain. I'd recommend removing the words "make more" as that really does sound like creating.